# Sets in Windows 10 (Insider Preview)

Tags: windows, shell

I am looking for the tool or utility that is used in the below screenshot. It seems to be an laternative to [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/), but it is not the same. Does anybody knows what is the tool name?

** **Please note how it nicely lets you to have mutiple tabs of command shells similar to what ConEmu does:**

[image]

Note that this is a Windows tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a VERY early release version of the tabbed interface Microsoft is developing for future versions of Windows. I've had it in my Fast Ring Insiders builds of Windows 10 for 6 months or more at this point.

The basic premise of the UI is that any window can be grouped with any other application window, and that is what you see in this screenshot: Windows Subsystem for Linux running embedded Ubuntu, then the CMD prompt, and then Powershell.

Microsoft original hoped to include "Sets" in 1803, last spring, but pulled it. I believe the feature was also pulled from 1809 for being still not polished enough.

Comment: Thank you! The mystery is solved. Do you know when it will be released to mainstream windows?

Comment: Considering it has already been pushed back twice, I will make no guesses. It's a cool tool, but if you're not expecting it it can be very confusing. I believe that, at best, it will be an option you can enable. And I also believe there's a good chance it may never see the light of day because of the UI overhaul it requires. It began as an attempt to just add tabs to File Explorer, I think.

Comment: Then I guess I continue using ConEmu  for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the feature of having multiple tabs? I remember seeing it from the windows insider program. It is called "Sets" where you can have tabs for every window and application but if this is not what you are talking about could you give some more information.